# LSA Type in OSPF

Tags: cisco

Can someone please explain to me Why I do have 9 LSA type 3 on Router B and D in this topology ?
[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Both router B and D are your ABRs (area border routers), which hold summaries for the areas they border, in your case they hold summaries for areas 1 and 0, and 0 and 2 respectively.  Type 3 LSA's are summary LSA's, which if you look at both routers A and E, they already have part of the answer for you; they both have "5" LSA type 3 summaries. Then if you look at router C in area 0, it has a total of "4" type 3 LSA's. Add these summaries up, "5" + "4", on each ABR, you have your "9" type 3 LSAs.